# How to add a structure to a linked list? in C

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to add a frame to a linked list of such structures, but instead of adding a new structure to the list each time, the program adds nothing, can anyone tell me what the problem is? Or give me a better exercise method?

The structures:

```
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    int duration;
    char* path;

} Frame;


// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

The functions:

```
FrameNode* addFrame(Frame* frame)
{
    char name[100] = { 0 };
    char path[100] = { 0 };
    int dur = 0;
    Frame* p = (Frame*)malloc(sizeof(Frame));

    printf("*** Creating a new frame ***\n");
    printf("Please insert frame path:\n");
    fgets(path, 100, stdin);
    path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
    strcpy(p->path, path);

    printf("Please insert frame duration <in miliseconds>:\n");
    scanf("%d", &dur);
    getchar();
    p->duration = dur;

    printf("Please chooce a name for a new frame:\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(list->frame->name, p->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("The name is already taken, Please enter another name\n");
            fgets(name, 100, stdin);
            name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
            strcpy(p->name, name);
        }
        list = list->next;
    }
    free(p);
    return p;
}

FrameNode* insertAtEnd(FrameNode** list, Frame* fr)
{
    if (*list)
    {
        FrameNode* help = *list;
        FrameNode* tmp = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));
        tmp->frame = addFrame(fr);
        while (help->next != NULL)
        {
            help = help->next;
        }
        help->next = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        list = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));
        FrameNode* tmp = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));
        tmp->frame = addFrame(fr);
        list = tmp;
    }
}
```

I really need help, I have to submit it by Sunday.
If you notice any more problems please tell me
Thank you to everyone!!!!!

Comment: What is the `frame` parameter for? It does not seem to be used.

Comment: So delete it? And do the function get nothing?

Comment: What is the global `list` variable supposed to point to? The `list = list->next;` line changes this variable so that it eventually becomes `NULL`. If it was pointing to the start of a list of nodes it no longer does so. Perhaps you should use a local variable there to avoid clobbering the global variable.

Comment: My problem is that the structure can't be printed afterwards and things don't get well (I deleted the free one) and simply if I print it shows an error:

0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003.

Comment: When you check if the chosen frame name already exists, find a match, and enter a new name, you are not checking the new name against the previous entries in the list.

Answer (score 1):

A separate struct for a linked list usually adds nothing but complexity. Why not just use:

```
struct my_frame {
    struct my_frame *next;
    char *name;
    int duration;
    char *path;
}
```

It reduces complexity and simplifies memory allocation.

A few personal preferences:
I suggest using a prefix to prevent generic names like "frame".
I also suggest dropping the typedef. It does nothing for you. It only adds obscurity.
Drop the capitals in type names. If you want to program in C, learn C don't try to make it look like C++, C# or Java.

Comment: It's a job given to me in school, I'm committed to doing the buildings in this way and all kinds of annoying things. My problem is why does it not include the structures in the linked list?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `addFrame` function you free `p`, but then you return it.

So in the line `tmp->frame = addFrame(fr);` in the function `insertAtEnd`, you assign a pointer that has been freed already, whose contents are unknown.

The solution is to simply remove the line `free(p)` in `addFrame`, but make sure that you have a free'ing mechanism later in your program for this list.

Edit: also, I now see that in the line `list = tmp;`, you are actually assigning a value to the local variable `list`, and what you should be doing is `*list = tmp` .

Comment: I deleted the line of free but it still doesn't work ...
On the contrary, now there is also an error and it is impossible to absorb more than three buildings and also what we have not printed.
This is the error that appears:
Exception thrown at 0x00031433 in RikaLevi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000002B.